# ruby returning true if a string consists an "a" and then a "z"

Tags: ruby

I need help on Writing a method that takes a string in and returns true if the letter "z" appears within three letters **after** an "a". You may assume               that the string contains only lowercase letters. here's what I have:

```
def nearby_az(string)
string.downcase!
i = 0
    while i < string.length
        if (string[i] == "a" && string[i] == "z")
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end
end

puts('nearby_az("baz") == true: ' + (nearby_az('baz') == true).to_s)
puts('nearby_az("abz") == true: ' + (nearby_az('abz') == true).to_s)
puts('nearby_az("abcz") == true: ' + (nearby_az('abcz') == true).to_s)
puts('nearby_az("a") == false: ' + (nearby_az('a') == false).to_s)
puts('nearby_az("z") == false: ' + (nearby_az('z') == false).to_s)
puts('nearby_az("za") == false: ' + (nearby_az('za') == false).to_s)
```

Comment: Your current expression will always be false.  You can't have the value be both a and z at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression would be the best for this. Try

```
def nearby_az(string)
    (string =~ /a.{0,2}z/) != nil
end
```

**EDIT:**
as per the "if statement required requirement" :)

```
def nearby_az(string)
    if (string =~ /a.{0,2}z/) != nil
        return true
    end
    return false
end
```

The way this code works is it searches the input string for an "a". After that, the period indicates that you can have any character. After that you have `{0,2}` which is a modifier of the period indicating you can have 0 to 2 of any character. After this you must have a "z", and this fulfills your must have a z within 3 characters of an "a".

I've saved this regex to regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/bB8lJ0/1) so you can try various inputs as well as change the regular expression around to understand it better.

Comment: ending the regexp with z woud be even better

Comment: if the following code can be written in an if statement, it would be better because thats what my instructor requires. thanks and if you can explain it too because I'm a beginner and would like to understand how the code works. thanks @ Martin Konecny: (string =~ /a.{0,2}z/) != nil

Comment: thank you for the edited "if statement" version and the explanation. can you also tell me what "=~" does or means and I know that "!= nil" means "is not equal to null" but if you can tell me how it pertains to code before it, as well. thank you.

Comment: Take a look here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-3D-7E+operator

if it doesn't find the regex pattern we created it will return a null. Otherwise it will return a number indicating the index in the string it found that pattern. So null means we didn't find anything, and a number means we did, and we simply convert those to boolean.

Comment: `!= nil` doesn't look nice. `!!` should be used.

Comment: To explicitly check for `nil`, `Object#nil?` is always preferred. `!!` is an antipattern. In this instance, though, `if string !~ expr` (or `unless string =~ expr`) alone would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

To fix you code you need to:

- increment i at the end of the loop.
- search the z letter within the 3 next letters
- return true when condition is met
- return false when getting out of the loop

Here is what it should look like:

```
def nearby_az(string)
    string.downcase!
    i = 0
    while i < string.length do
        return true if string[i] == "a" && string[i+1,3].include?(?z)
        i+=1
    end
    return false
end
```